# two animations at same time for one character without an avatar mask in unity 2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development, 2d-games

I have frame by frame arms/hand attack and body jump in png sequence from my After Effects projects, and want to display it when jump and attack, like the body doing the jump animation the arms/hands do the attack animation, cause the animation is ready to use don't want to set up an avatar mask, want to play both at same time, the body on top of the arms or vice versa. Is this possible? I don't find any documentation or other forum with this approach.

I tried to use animation controller layers, setting the weight of each one to 1. In the layer that has the animation for the arms/hands, I included the settings for synchronization and additive blending, all guided by certain forums or video tutorials. However, I can't get them to play at the same time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.